# Reading file names instead of data inside files

Tags: r, matrix

Hello you wonderful people.
I am new to R and matlab and been searching on the net to answer this but cant find anything.The problem is when I create a final matrix it just lists filenames.

The background behind this, so that you understand what I mean:

I am using R with inbuilt matlab and trying to read data from 15 .txt files.These 15 files all have 2 columns of data and 1686 rows. I am supposed to put these files into a vector of type list using a dir() function. I am then to access each element of this vector and pass it to read.table() function so that I can create a matrix N, which contains the data. As mentioned earlier, these files have 2 columns and I am told to extract the 1st column of each file and put it in the ith column of a matrix called X. X has 16 rows to represent the 15 files and a header row and 1687 columns for the data and dismissing the first column.

When I type X in the console bit of R studio it comes up with the Error in X[i, ] <- t(N[, 1]) :   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length.

I thought fair enough, I'll change X to a 15 by 15 matrix and it instead came up with a matrix containing the .txt file names, instead of the data I wanted. 
I first want to solve this error of file names before I try to solve the multiple replacement length error. 
**Is their something wrong in my code?** I have written the code below as if for 15 x 15 matrix to demonstrate the file name problem rather than 16 x 1687 as original:

```
# Clear workspace
rm(list=ls())
# Close any open graphics devices
graphics.off()
# Load additional packages
require(matlab, quietly=TRUE)
# Activate functions
source("auto.r")
source("mncn.r")
source("rangescale.r")
source("hcluster2.r")


filelist <- dir(path = "~/MSc/Course/Module3", pattern = "*.txt", all.files = FALSE,
    full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,
    ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE)

for (i in 1:length(filelist)) assign(filelist[i], read.table(filelist[i], sep="\t", header=T, row.names=1))

filelist <- as.matrix(filelist)
N <- filelist
X <- matrix (nrow = 15, ncol = 15)
X[i,] <- t(N[,1])
```

Comment: NO worries guys, fiiiiinaaaaaallly managed to do it took me hours of experimenting with a script a friend had sent me. They sent me this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOOOH MYYY GOODNESS!!! toook me hours but managed to solve this by experimenting with a script that was given to me! 
**I amendeded it to this:**

```
sam <- dir(path = "~/MSc/Course/Module3", pattern = "*.txt", all.files = FALSE,
                full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,  
                ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE)

X <- matrix(nrow=1, ncol=1686)

for (i in 1:length(sam)) {N <- read.table(sam[i], sep="\t", header=F, row.names=NULL)
                          X <- rbind (X, N[,2])  }
rownames(X) <- c("temp", "A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3", "C1", "C2", "C3", "D1", "D2", "D3", "E1", "E2", "E3")
X <- X[-1,]
```

Answer (score 1):

try out the apply functions, `apply`,`sapply`,`mapply` etc.

The one you want here since you are working with a list of files is `lapply`

Something similar to

`datalist <- lapply(filelist, function(x) read.table(x, header = T))`

So as an example: let me makes some text files

```
dat1 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10),
                   y = rnorm(10))
dat2 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(5),
                   y = rnorm(5),
                   z = rnorm(5))

tmp <- c('dat1','dat2')
lapply(tmp, function(x) write.table(get(x), file = paste0(x,'.txt'), quote = F, row.names = F))
```

Now, here's what I would do in your situation.

```
filelist <- dir(path = '.', pattern = "*.txt", all.files = FALSE,
                full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,
                ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE)
> filelist
[1] "dat1.txt" "dat2.txt"

datalist <- lapply(filelist, function(x) read.table(x, header = T))

> datalist[1]
[[1]]
x          y
1   0.66407205  0.6380669
2  -0.85676390  0.3987090
3   1.23954448  0.7414505
4  -0.11823676 -0.1658559
5   1.41603036  0.5585108
6   2.16411026 -1.0918350
7  -0.54033389  0.3603718
8   0.01530916  0.5687294
9   0.06244237 -1.1000696
10 -0.15826680 -2.5999726

> datalist[2]
[[1]]
x           y           z
1  0.09159357 -0.80349348  0.04728642
2  0.21526376 -0.03353738  0.77563529
3  0.17405957 -0.68228875  0.72500158
4 -1.81829362 -1.59196023 -1.25275570
5 -1.92814438 -0.07139163 -0.08759747
```

And if you need to access individual data sets

```
> tmp <- datalist[[2]]
> dim(tmp)
[1] 5 3
> names(tmp)
[1] "x" "y" "z"
> tmp$y
[1] -0.80349348 -0.03353738 -0.68228875 -1.59196023 -0.07139163
```